# Extern Lambda Function

Tags: c++, lambda, extern

How could I extern the following lambda function from a source file to a header so I can use it in a different source file?

```
const auto perform_checks = [&]()
{
    const auto func =
        GetFunctionPEB(static_cast<LPWSTR>(L"ntdll.dll"), "NtSetDebugFilterState");

    auto* func_bytes = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(func);
    if (is_hooked(func_bytes))
    {
        ProtectionThread();
    }
};
```

Comment: Use a normal inline function in the header?

Comment: i want it to be a lambda function, im using c++ clr and if it's a lambda you can't view the code with any .net inspector because it seems "virtualized"

Comment: Will std::function help? I think by making it extern, you will probably undo what you are trying to achieve anyway. You could also look at using a callback.

Comment: Looks lke an XY problem. lambda is an expression that yields an instance of function-like object, its type is anonymous, that's probably why tools you try to fail. It's not necessary that something else wouldn't recognize it though. And making that object external you invite problems with capture by reference because of csptured objects lifespan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well maybe this in the direction you want

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

// In header file
extern std::function<void(void)> externedFunction;

// In c++ file
std::function<void(void)> externedFunction = [](){
    std::string msg = "performing checks";

    const auto perform_checks = [msg]()
    {
        std::cout << msg << std::endl;
    };
    return perform_checks;

}();
```

It is kind of a dubious use case. However note I capture the *msg* by value. If you capture by reference you can't return the lambda because you will capture a reference to a stack variable and you end up with undefined behavior which probably means your app crashes

Alternately you could do.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

// In header file
extern std::function<void(void)> externedFunction;



// In c++ file
static std::string msg = "performing checks";

std::function<void(void)> externedFunction = 
    [&msg]()
    {
        std::cout << msg << std::endl;
    };
```

But you are probably better off just with a function. But I guess you have your reasons.

Comment: note that your first example can just be a plain function pointer rather than `std::function` as the lambda is non-capturing

Comment: sure it could but the OP is asking how to extern a lambda. I mention at the end that they probably would be better off with a function but if they really want to it's up to them.